# How do I create a rule for a class with multiple properties in OWL/GraphDB?

Tags: owl, ontology, graphdb, owlim

`Animal_Lover` class is a class that has three properties called `hasPet`.

Smith raises three animals and belongs to `Person` class.

At this point, how do I write rule(.pie) to automatically include smith in the animal_lover class when the rule works?

```
Prefices {
    test : http://www.example.com/test#
    rdf : http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#
    owl : http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#
    xsd : http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#
    rdfs : http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#
}
Axioms {}

Rules {
    Id: rule1
        a <test:hasPet> b
        a <test:hasPet> d
        a <test:hasPet> c           
        -----------------------
        a <rdf:type> <test:Animal_Lover>
}
```

this rule does not work.

Comment: and you did add the rule file properly?

Comment: and what means does not work? and shouldn't you add constraints that  `b != d`and  `b != c` and `c != d` ?

Comment: @AKSW Yes. I added a rule file, added constraints, but it did not work. And 'not work' means the rule did not fire. I also tried the following command. `INSERT DATA { [] <http://www.ontotext.com/owlim/system#reinfer> [] }`

Comment: Works for me as expected, I uploaded the custom ruleset `Prefices { test : http://www.example.com/test# rdf : http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns# owl : http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl# xsd : http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema# rdfs : http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema# } Axioms {} Rules { Id: rule1 a <test:hasPet> b [Constraint b != d, b != c] a <test:hasPet> d [Constraint d != b, d != c] a <test:hasPet> c [Constraint c != b, c != d] ----------------------- a <rdf:type> <test:Animal_Lover> }`

Comment: created a repository with the custom ruleset , inserted some data `prefix test: <http://www.example.com/test#>
insert data { 
 test:a test:hasPet test:b1,test:b2, test:b3  .
}` and finally did a simple `select * where { 
 ?s ?p ?o .
} limit 100 
` returns `test:a rdf:type test:Animal_Lover`

Answer (score 0):

Did you look in the log for any errors? This line seems suspect to me, I think the brackets should be on different lines

`Axioms {}`